# Why does a Global object lead to non working code?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-7.0-nougat

I have a pretty basic android application. Most of it is still from the template. I use an own class library for a XMPP client. Now what is happening, is that if I declare a global TextView for use in events or different methods(OnCreate, OnResume etc.) my events seem not to get raised. 
My library is definetly not the reason since I tested it under different circumstances.

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public XMPPClient client;
        TextView consoleText;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            fab.Click += FabOnClick;

            //consoleText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.consoleText);

            client = new XMPPClient("10.0.2.2", 5222, "chris3", "Define")
            {
                AuthenticationInfo = true
            };

            client.OnPublishEvent += Client_OnPublishEvent;
            client.OnConnection += Client_OnConnection;
            client.OnMessageReceived += Client_OnMessageReceived;
        }

        private void Client_OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            //consoleText.Text += "\nMessage: " + e.text + " from " + e.from;
            Log.Debug("mytag", "Message!");
        }

        private void Client_OnPublishEvent(object sender, SubscriptionEventArgs e)
        {
            //consoleText.Text += "\nPublication: " + e.title + " with content " + e.content + " at " + e.published;
            Log.Debug("mytag", "Publication");
        }

        private void Client_OnConnection(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
        {
            //consoleText.Text += "\nConnection status changed: " + e.Status;
            Log.Debug("mytag", "ConnectionChange");
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;
            if (id == Resource.Id.action_subscribe)
            {
                client.Subscribe("Node1");
                Log.Debug("mytag", "Subscribed");
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            View view = (View) sender;
            client.Connect();
        }
    }
```

When the TextView consoleText object is there, my OnConnection-event gets fired in the beginning, and when I close the client.
However, if it isn't there, every event works perfectly fine.
For now as I am a beginner with Xamarin I'm really interested on the source of the problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin much, but I would guess that it has something to do with crossthreading accessing UI controls. You probably should `Invoke` in on the UI thread.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're assigning to 'consoleText' anywhere in your OnCreate method?

Comment: @Tubif-Fux what's the error message you receive? What's the external & internal stack trace? Could you please share it so we can help you better? Also try to place an exception catch point, so you can see exactly where the exception is raised

Comment: @Saamer There were no errors. That was the problem. The TextView just didn't change and seemed to freeze the program until I call my client.Close() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to wrap the text assignments to be processed against the primary dispatcher (UI Thread).

So for example it would look something like this.

```
private void Client_OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
        consoleText.Text += "\nMessage: " + e.text + " from " + e.from;
    });

    Log.Debug("mytag", "Message!");
}
```

Give that a try and let me know if it still errors, don't forget you'll need to wrap all of the `consoleText.Text` assignments inside of this.

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
});

// You might not need the Activity part, I can't remember exactly which 
// one it is for an AppCompatActivity.

RunOnUiThread(() => {
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks :) I'm going to look into that so next time I know what is actually going on.

Comment: @TubifFux it's likely that the XMPPClient uses Tasks to process events, and these are executed on a different thread. They probably have some documentation on it hidden away somewhere, I'm glad the answer helped though.